# Html Css Fluid Layout Not Working

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="template">
    <div class="template-header"></div>
    <div class="template-navigation"></div>
    <div class="template-content">
        <div class="template-content-left"></div>
        <div class="template-content-middle"></div>
        <div class="template-content-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="template-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Using this css:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html
{
    height: 100%;   
    min-height: 100%;
}

.template
{
    height: 100%;
}

.template-header
{
    background: gray;
    height: 100px;
}

.template-navigation
{
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
}

.template-content
{
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.template-content-left
{
    float: left;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

.template-content-middle
{
    background: magenta;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 400px);
}

.template-content-right
{
    float: right;
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

.template-footer
{
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I can't get `template-content` to fill the remaining height and i can't get `template-content-middle` to fill the remaining width.

The following must be fixed heights:
template-header
template-navigation
template-footer

The following must be fixed widths:
template-content-left
template-content-right

Looking for a cross-browser solution. Would like to avoid javascript/jquery if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `height: 100%` works if the parent has height 100% (this applies to relative and static), which parent has 100% too and so on up to the body/html tag each parent must have 100%. So in your case that won't be a good idea, so you should use javascript and caculate the height in order to apply it.

Comment: I do have html, body set to 100% height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying the following css will fill the height

```
html, body, .template-content{
 height:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8dYsB/)

You can  either change the height of the header, nav  and footer to % and and set the contents height equal to (100% -  total height of other elements in %) or use js to calculate the height of content.

For the content in middle, you don't actually need a middle div, just float the left and right divs to `left` and `right`  respectively, the content in container div will be then automatically rendered in the space available in the middle as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8dYsB/9/)

Or you can apply `position:relative` for the container, remove the `float` and apply `display:inline-block` for left and right, then absolutely position the left and right div appropriately relative to the container, and add `padding-left` and `padding-right` equal to the width of left and right divs respectively, which will cause the content in container div to appear in the middle.

As in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8dYsB/10/)

Or if ancient browser compatibility is not an issue, use css3 `calc()` function and set the height of container as

```
.template-content
{
 border: 1px solid magenta;
 height: calc(100% - 200px); 
}
```

and for the middle div

```
.template-content-middle
{
 float:left;
 background: magenta;
 width: calc(100% - 400px);
 height: 100%;
}
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8dYsB/3/)

*side note: It's better to use `background` for testing layouts than `border` since border will break the calculations in normal rendering, If you want to avoid that, look into a whole new topic : [CSS Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)*

Comment: Setting height to 100% on .template-content causes an overflow on .template.

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c i did mention to set the height of other elements in % and set content height as 100% - their total height in %.

Comment: I would like fixed heights for header, navigation and footer. And fixed widths for template-content-left and template-content-right. So that it looks consistent across any resolution. Used your suggestion regarding background... much better!

Comment: This can be done easily in **modern browsers** ,Is older browser support much important? @__@ if so you'll need to use js...

Comment: I would like the site to be usable by as many people as possible. I am  not sure of what the ratio is of older vs. new browsers.

Comment: If you want fixed left and right panels, you just need to float them `left` and `right`, you don't need a `middle` panel, the content in the container will automatically appear in middle as in this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/8dYsB/6/

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c check this for knowing the browser support for the last solution i mentioned using `calc()` http://caniuse.com/calc

i added some more basic possible solutions using css with little compromises, i hate using js for layout..! :)

Comment: Marked this is answer. Ended up using Calc and float: left and float: right for template-content-left and template-content-right respectively. Updated answer to reflect css changes.

Answer (score -3):

```
<pre><code>.template-content
{
border: 1px solid magenta;
overflow:auto;
}
```